# Flask-Restful: How to send non-json POST argument?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a problem making the simple (non-json) arguments work with POST. Just taking the simple [example](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#full-example) from their tutorials, I can't make a unit test where the task is passing as an argument. However task is never passed in. Its none.

```
class TodoList(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('task', type = str)
        super(TodoList, self).__init__()

    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        #args['task'] is None, but why?
        return TODOS[args['task']], 201
```

Unit test:

```
def test_task(self):
        rv = self.app.post('todos', data='task=test')
        self.check_content_type(rv.headers)
        resp = json.loads(rv.data)
        eq_(rv.status_code, 201)
```

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `'task=test'` `test_client` do not set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, because you put string to input stream. So flask can't detect form and read data from form and `reqparse` will return `None` for any values for this case.

To fix it you must set up content type or use dict `{'task': 'test'}` or tuple.

Also for request testing better to use `client = self.app.test_client()` instead `app = self.app.test_client()`, if you use `FlaskTesting.TestCase` class, then just call `self.client.post`.

Comment: You mean by 'to fix it you must set up content type', shall I set it to `{'Content-Type':'application/json'}`? Hence better off using json after all all together, right?

Comment: I told about `rv = self.client.post('/', data='task=test', content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')` or `rv = self.client.post('/', data={'task':'test'})`. But it isn't json, its html form format. If you want use json you must send json `rv = self.client.post('/', data='{"task":"test"}', content_type='application/json')` and parse json `self.reqparse.add_argument('task', type=str, location='get_json')`.